# Subtrair valor de argumento de entrada shellscript

Tags: bash, shell-script

Tenho o script abaixo que imprime na tela os números pares de 1 até o argumento de entrada.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq 1 ($1)); do
    if [ $(($i % 2)) -eq 0 ]
    then
    echo "$i \c"
    fi
done
```

Por exemplo, para a excução do script com o argumento 10 o script imprime o seguinte

```
2 4 6 8 10
```

Gostaria que o script imprimisse apenas até o valor da entrada menos 1. Ou seja, `$1-1` que para este caso é `9`.

---

Já tentei a seguinte modificação sem sucesso.

```
for i in $(seq 1 (( $1 - 1 )) ); do
    if [ $(($i % 2)) -eq 0 ]
    then
    echo "$i \c"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você só precisa de um `$` na expressão de subtração (e remover os espaços):

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq 1 $(($1 - 1))); do
  if [ $(($i % 2)) -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "$i"
  fi
done
```

Extraindo uma variável fica mais legível:

```
#!/bin/bash
last=$(($1 - 1))
for i in $(seq 1 $last); do
  if [ $(($i % 2)) -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "$i"
  fi
done
```

Como `1` nunca vai ser impresso, nem mesmo o `if` é necessário:

```
#!/bin/bash
last=$(($1 - 1))
for i in $(seq 2 2 $last); do echo $i; done
```

Várias opções! :)

Comment: Valeu! Uns 40 min depois que postei a pergunta consegui. Era realmente o `$` que faltou. 
Quanto a otimização do 1, eu preciso dele pq essa é só uma parte do código. O restante vai usar os ímpares.

Comment: Esse `seq` de passo 2 é bem legal. Não sabia q dava pra fazer isso.

Answer (score 1):

Também consegui da seguinte forma

```
for i in $(seq 1  `expr $1 - 0`); do
    if [ $(($i % 2)) -eq 0 ]
    then
    echo "$i,\c"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Para otimizar mais, você nem precisa usar o `if`, pode aplicar direto o operador `&&` (**AND_IF**), assim:  `[ $(($i % 2)) -eq 0 ] &&  echo "$i,\c"`